# Centos: no such package(s) for specific nginx version

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, nginx, source

I tried to build a customized nginx with specific nginx version with module in https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth

I setup the nginx repo

```
# nginx.repo

[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

I do see the nginx-1.10.2-1.el7.ngx.src.rpm in "http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/SRPMS/" and download it with

```
curl http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/SRPMS/nginx-1.10.2-1.el7.ngx.src.rpm -o nginx-1.10.2-1.el7.ngx.src.rpm
```

Yet while I tried to run yum-buildep to install dependencies, I keep getting the error of **"No such package(s): nginx-1.10.2-1.el7.ngx.src.rpm"**. Any idea? Thanks.

```
yum-builddep --enablerepo=nginx nginx-1.10.2-1.el7.ngx.src.rpm
```

The output in detail

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Enabling base-source repository
Enabling epel-source repository
Enabling extras-source repository
Enabling updates-source repository
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * epel: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * epel-source: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * extras: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * updates: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
Checking for new repos for mirrors
No such package(s): nginx-1.10.2-1.el7.ngx.src.rpm
```

Comment: Why not just `yum install nginx`? Yum will install all of the dependencies along with it.

Comment: I want to customize the nginx with module ngx_http_aws_auth_module here https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from doing that after you've installed it. In fact, that's how it's meant to be done.

Comment: Follow this guide, basically you can install nginx normally then compile module with `configure` and then copy it under `modules` folder of nginx: `https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-dynamic-modules-nginx-plus/`

Comment: @TuyenPham Thanks Tuyen. I think I sort of mislead by https://github.com/ajdruff/nginx-naxsi-rpm/blob/master/how-to-build-your-own-nginx-rpm.md ,and tried to build rpm from scratch. So If I understand correctly, the solution in "https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-dynamic-modules-nginx-plus" is pretty same as "https://github.com/ajdruff/nginx-naxsi-rpm/blob/master/how-to-build-your-own-nginx-rpm.md", except the latter one tried to build it automatically in rpm, correct?

Comment: @TuyenPham BTW, I notice the link you post is for nginx plus. Does the solution also work for regular nginx?

Comment: The title is `for nginx and nginx plus`. You can try to compile from scratch but seem nginx supports easier way to achieve the same purpose.